# Angular 2 with PHP backend design structure thoughts

Tags: javascript, php, json, angular, twig

I have a huge project, which has grown over the years. I would like to change, change not refactor, from jQuery to Angular 2 in the frontend (this is not a question on refactor jQhery to Angular, which has been discussed a lot here. Also, I think it's not compareable).

Ok, first of all Angular 2 does not have controllers anymore in the meaning of AngularJS. So, we got only compontents. I think it would be the best way, to divide the page into header, content and footer components.

With the change to Angular 2 I would also change my backend to the Twig Rendering Engine. That wouldn't be a problem, because we can change the symbol of Twig e. g. from `{{` to `<%` and `}}` to `%>`. To clearify if it should be rendered on the frontend or the backend.

My question is: What is better? Rendering on the client / frontend or the backend? I Could use Twig (with an output buffer) for the main part and could it send back to the client via JSON, e. g.:

```
{
header: {
   error: false
},
view: // html escaped content here
}
```

In this way, I could get the data from the database and put it prerendered all together, which may contain directives which are rendered at the frontend.

On the other hand, I could use some static template partials (for loops etc.), which just set their values returned from JSON into that Angular 2 HTML Template. On that way, I would have huge rendering on client side. So, what are the thoughts of Angular 2 about that? I mean, I am not sure, if this is really a good thing for mobile clients like mobile phones or other thin clients. I am creating an responsive template, so I have to look after that criteria.

What do you think, what is better or how are you dealing with that?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Depends on your real needs.

Nowadays it's very common the Single page + REST API architecture. If this project is really big, with a lot of requests per second and so many data to load, this chose would be awesome! This way you'll distribute the responsibility of processing. Other advantage: you can focus in the Client side and really improve the project UX and performance. There is so many good and bad points, but I really like this approach!

But you really should study what is better for your project! Wrong decision can broke it!

You should see how much this software will weight on the browsers and if you really need a complex processing at client side. If its only will print something at the browser, the common approach is fine too.

Besides, it's cool you analyse your team, their skills and knowledge about the technology you chose. You have to consider the learning time and etc. There is a lot of variables to  see.

I recommend you to read:

- http://adamsilver.io/articles/the-disadvantages-of-single-page-applications/
- http://www.eikospartners.com/blog/multi-page-web-applications-vs.-single-page-web-applications

Comment: Ok thanks, I think that helped. Not sure actually. I also thought that this article was helpful: https://hackernoon.com/10-things-i-learned-making-the-fastest-site-in-the-world-18a0e1cdf4a7#.edx295us6 after reading so, I would render the most at the backend with twig and just put the escaped html string back to frontend. A server usually have multi-core cpu at least 10 times faster than any mobile device.

Comment: So I think use the twig template is the right choice!